# Conditional Regex replace to add dashes

Tags: c#, regex

Ok, so I need to design a regex to insert dashes. Im tasked with building a web API function that returns a specifically formatted string based upon input parameters. For some reason that hasn't been made clear to me, the source data isn't properly formatted, and I need to reformat the data with dashes in the correct place.

Depending on the first two characters and string length there is an optional third dash. Fortunately Im not concerned what those characters are. This system is a passthrough, so garbage in, garbage out. However, i do need to make sure the dashes are spaced appropriately on length.

```
Structure               Types
XX-9999999999-XX        AB
XX-9999999999-99        CD, EF
XX-9999999999-XXX-99    GH
XX-9999999999-XX-99     IJ, KL
```

For Example:

```
AB123456789044 should be AB-01234567890-44 and 
GH1234567890YYY99 becomes GH-01234567890-YYY-99.
```

Thus far ive gotten to this point.

```
^(\w\w)(\d{10})(\w{2,3})(\d\d)?$
```

Which leads to my Question(s)

1) Im attempting to replace with $1-$2-$3-$4 However, whenever there is a fourth section of decimals, such as the case with IJ, its hard to distinguish between that and AB in the replace.

Ive gotten GH-01234567890-YY-99 And GH-01234567890-YY-.

How do I reference a conditional capture group in a replace string such that the dash relating to it only shows up if the grouping exists?

Comment: In all honesty I wouldn't use regex for this.  Instead I'd use `StartsWith` to determine which case and then it's some simple substring and concatenation to get the desired result.

Comment: This is possible, but you should only do that with regex if you must validate the string you are re-formatting. If you only expect strings in one and the same format, the comment above applies.

Comment: Im honestly not entirely sure how much validation I need, as I know little about the source.

Comment: What happens in the case of something like `PP9999999999XX99` or `AA9999999999XX`? Are there other possible formats, or just the 6 you specified?

Comment: Ok. So just fished some more requirements out of them on validation. I need to whole sale re-think the question and requirements.    I think a length based pattern is good enough.

Comment: @ctwheels Im reformatting the question entirely.

Comment: What's the difference between `[AB]` and `[CD, EF]` formats?

Comment: One follows with numbers, one follows with letters.

Comment: Your examples are incorrect. You have `AB123456789044` and it has **11** digits plus **2** tail digits. However, in your structure there are **10** digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need conditional replacements, and C# doesn't support those. So you've got to do the replacements programmatically. Something like:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"([A-Z]{2})-?(\d{10})-?(?:([A-Z]{2,3})|(\d{2}))-?(\d{2})?", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    resultString = regexObj.Replace(subjectString, new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Error handling
}

public String ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    // Vary the replacement text in C# as needed
    return "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5";
}
```

I haven't paid too much attention to the actual RegEx here, as it seems like you know what you're doing with it. I just included some conditional hyphens in case the data are quite dirty (partially formatted). Obviously you have to edit the "return" part of this, using conditionals in case any of the captures are blank. I haven't worked out that logic for you, as C# isn't my strength.